Kohler kitchen faucet stuck bad - won't come off
Trying to remove a Kohler kitchen faucet and it just doesn't want to budge.
The ring nut from the bottom is seized tight. I tried hammering with a punch in the screw holes to no effect. I tried to drill a hole in the nut and instead managed to drill through the threaded pipe.
Next step: I cut off the top of the faucet to see if I could drop it down through the hole in the granite counter. Nope. Doesn't look like this fitting will drop through the hole.
Any ideas ? Space under the sink/counter is super tight to work.


Removed : Notched the top after faucet was cut off, and used a screw driver and hammer to turn it from the topside.
No damage to any thing other than the faucet that was already not working.


Loosen the 2 screws that acts as a pinch hold to the bottom of the countertop.

Yes loosen the screws, or take them out completely and the ring will spin off, or it should when the threads are not mucked up.

The screws have been removed since I took that last picture. I've ground through part of the ring with a dremel and it still won't budge :-(

....and that is why the statement.  "when the threads are not mucked up."   Now you just need to cut the ring off.

If you think you have to destroy anything to dismantle it, you are probably doing it wrong and should stop and seek expert assistance instead.

@keshlam, too late for that.

Before I cut anything, I tried removing the screws fully, sprayed the area with PB Blaster to break up the rust - gave it about 30 minutes to work. The ring is nicely seized to the bottom of the granite counter. I've now ground away almost a quarter of the ring and the ring still will not budge. I appreciate the comment about seeking expert assistance but if I had a penny for every time I had to fix something after paying the expert to do a shoddy job, ....... P.S> I got advice from an expert plumber before I even started the project.

Then why ask here?

@RMDman - I ask here because I usually get good and useful advice here. Something arbitrary like keshlam's advice is simply not helpful. Sometimes plumbing fittings need to be cut out and licensed plumbers do the same as well.

Congrats on your victory!

Posted that comment before I saw the statement that the threads are ruined. In that case, yes of course, force maybe the only solution.

I think at this point you use a reciprocating saw and cut a slot from the topside into the inner side of the faucet and then use a chisel to remove the pieces.   This video shows the technique well - https://youtube.com/shorts/5HHe7oloAD0?si=UXPOULFtUY8iKajm

@FreshCodemonger - Thanks. That's what I ended up doing.

The installer of the original faucet had epoxied the fitting to the underside of the granite counter which made it impossible to unscrew from the bottom.
After a couple hours of trying to grind out the nut with a dremel I gave up and started from the top.
THe solution is to cut the faucet off from the top and a couple inches above the counter so as to not damage the counter. Then, I was able to cut a notch in the top and use a chisel and hammer to turn it which broke the epoxy seal on the underside. This was a Kohler faucet.
The replacement faucet, a Delta faucet once it's cut from the top will likely simply fall down into the hole.I didn't use any epoxy on the install of the new faucet. The pressure fitting nut holds it well in place and a caulk on the topside makes sure water won't drip in.
